# How does Apache resolve the path to error_log?

Tags: apache-httpd, logs

In my `httpd.conf` located in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` there is the line:

```
ErrorLog logs/error_log
```

But the path to the log file is: `/var/log/httpd/error_log`

How does Apache Webserver resolve the path to the error_log file?

Answer (score 6):

Found the solution:

If the path of the ErrorLog does not begin with "/" then the
path of the `ServerRoot` (also in httpd.conf) is prepended.
The `ServerRoot` in my configuration is `/etc/httpd`.

So `logs/error_log` is changed to `/etc/httpd/logs/error_log`.

The path `/etc/httpd/logs/error_log` is a relative link to `../../var/log/httpd`
If this relative path is converted to an absolute path the result is:

```
/var/log/httpd/error_log
```